# Rails authenticity_token cannot be verified when submitting requests to API::V1 module controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authenticity-token

I've come across a very strange problem with Rails 5. I've two controllers, first as `users_controller` and second as `api/v1/users_controller`. Both these controllers have a `register` action. I am trying to post a form to both these controllers. This form is created as below,

```rb
 <%= form_tag('v2/register/user', {id: "add-user-form", class: "jiffle-form", role: "form"}) do%>
   #form body
   <%= submit_tag("Resigter", data: {i18n: "register"}, class:  "btn btn-lg btn-block btn-blue", id: "add-user", type: "submit") %>
<% end %>
```

**Routes**,

```
post "register" => "users#create", :as => "user_registeration_submit"
post "v2/register/user" => "api/v1/users#create"
```

When I use `/register` url to submit the form it gets processed successfully. However, when I use `v2/register/user` url to submit the form I am getting `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` error.

**Params**

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ADNTIp9alRB/ujRhkoqNuDkzdW6ANfcl/MbPjGLwVd6nwVuG5oi+uVhE9MeZo+1MeyKLbwZYNV31Vy/VH3M2bg==", "sfdc_token"=>"",
 "email"=>"[FILTERED]", "first_name"=>"kjl", "last_name"=>"jk", "contact_no"=>"894892849", "company_name"=>"j", "title"=>"kj",
 "internal_366vagan2"=>"", "consent"=>"true",
 "commit"=>"Register"}
```

When I use ajax to submit the form to `api/v1/users_controller` with **X-CSRF-TOKEN** header in the request it works fine.

Where do I make a change to get my api/v1 controller to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write in application_controller.rb

```
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception, unless: -> { request.format.json? }
```

And set default format will be json in routes.rb file

But better approach:

In your case, you have to create two namespaces, one for handing API response and second one for FORM handling. Use namespaces in routes.rb file accordingly. And also two different base controller accordingly that inherits from ApplicationController.

For API

```
class Api::V1::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception, unless: -> { request.format.json? }
end
```

And set default format will be json in routes.rb file

```
 resources :tasks, defaults: {format: :json}
```

For FORM View

Use bydefault settings, or

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
#In this case, comment it from main application_controller.rb file:protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Note: here Admin and Api are two namespaces. And routes.rb file will look like:

```
#For admin
namespace :admin do

end 

#For Api
namespace :api do
    scope module: :v1 do

    end
end
```

Hope it will work :)